# Magento add a column to backend newsletter gridview

Tags: php, magento, admin

In the magento system, I added the columns `subscriber_firstname` and `subscriber_lastname` to the `newsletter_subscriber` db table.

In the admin area of magento, I want the Newsletter>Newsletter Subscribers grid table to show:

- customer first name if it exists, otherwise show `newsletter_subscriber.subscriber_firstname` if it exists, otherwise show nothing
- customer last name if it exists, otherwise show `newsletter_subscriber.subscriber_lastname` if it exists, otherwise show nothing

Which magento files do I need to edit to make this work?  How do I go about editing the files to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Newsletter/Subscriber/Grid.php

You'll want to condition this based off if subscriber_firstname or subscriber_lastname have values or not:

```
    $this->addColumn('subscribername', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('Subscriber First Name'),
        'index'     => 'subscriber_firstname',
        'default'   =>    '----'
    ));
```

Also, make sure to make a copy of the core files and NOT edit them directly!

Answer (score 0):

the quick and easy solution is to create a column render and select the correct field based on the subscriber type e.g.

app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Newsletter/Subscriber/Renderer/FirstName.php

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Renderer_FirstName extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract {
    public function render(Varien_Object $row) {
        $value = '';
        if ($row->getData('type') == 2) {
            $value = $row->getData('customer_firstname');
        }
        else {
            $value = $row->getData('subscriber_firstname');
        }
        return $value;
    }
}
```

then add your render to a local copy of the subscriber grid class
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Newsletter/Subscriber/Grid.php

```
    $this->addColumn('firstname', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('First Name'),
        'index'     => 'customer_firstname',
        'default'   => '----',
        'renderer'  => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Renderer_FirstName'
    ));
```

Note. the search and sort will not work on the subscriber name fields, to get this working you will need to extend app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Mysql4/Subscriber/Collection.php